# how events are dispatched from event queue

Tags: java, swing, awt, awt-eventqueue

I read a statement in Java docs related to event queue saying that "note that events being posted to the eventQueue can be coalesced" . What is the meaning of this line?

Comment: Swing paint events get "merged" so not too much redundant painting is done.

Answer (score 2):

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html**

> **postEvent**
>
> ```
> public void postEvent(AWTEvent theEvent)
> ```
>
> Posts a 1.1-style event to the `EventQueue`. If there is an existing
>   event on the queue with the same ID and event source, the source
>   `Component's coalesceEvents` method will be called.
>
> **Parameters:**    `theEvent` - an instance of `java.awt.AWTEvent`, or a subclass of it
>   **Throws:**    `NullPointerException` - if theEvent is `null`

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html**

> **coalesceEvents**
>
> ```
> protected AWTEvent coalesceEvents(AWTEvent existingEvent,
>                                   AWTEvent newEvent)
> ```
>
> Potentially coalesce an event being posted with an existing event.
>   This method is called by `EventQueue.postEvent` if an event with the
>   same ID as the event to be posted is found in the queue (both events
>   must have this component as their source). This method either returns
>   a coalesced event which replaces the existing event (and the new event
>   is then discarded), or `null` to indicate that no combining should be
>   done (add the second event to the end of the queue). Either event
>   parameter may be modified and returned, as the other one is discarded
>   unless `null` is returned.
>
> This implementation of `coalesceEvents`coalesces two event types:
>   mouse move (and drag) events, and paint (and update) events. For mouse
>   move events the last event is always returned, causing intermediate
>   moves to be discarded. For paint events, the new event is coalesced
>   into a complex `RepaintArea` in the peer. The new `AWTEvent` is always
>   returned.
>
> **Parameters:**    `existingEvent` - the event already on the `EventQueue`    `newEvent` - the event being posted to the
>   `EventQueue`     Returns: a coalesced event, or `null` indicating that
>   no coalescing was done

Comment: AFAIK postEvent clean_up queue, all events are lost and new event(s) are fired, maybe one of reason why there is SecondaryLoop (since Java7)